# Using gdb -i=mi integration in emacs 24

Tags: emacs, gdb

I'm checking out a segfault in one of our apps.  A short time after starting the app, the main `gdb` status bar changes to:

> (Debugger:run [signal-received])

A `(gdb)` prompt appears but the contents of all other windows remain unchanged (empty).  Typing anything at the prompt does nothing - `gdb` appears to be hanging.  Running the same steps on the `command line` results in the expected output from `gdb` with a complete and correct backtrace.

This is my first time debugging with the `-i=mi` integration between `emacs` and `gdb`. I'm using `emacs` 24.2 and `gdb` 7.5.

Are there any suggestions on how I can debug this further?

Is it possible to reduce the level of integration?  Would that allow me to determine which area is causing the problem?

A final point is that the initial loading of the app takes around 70s compared with around 3s from the `command line`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load time can be reduced by setting `gdb-create-source-file-list` to `nil` (use customize). See the documentation for what this does and why it substantially increases load times in some instances.

Comment: Spot on.  I'd actually downgraded to 23 because of this - so hopefully now I can stick with the latest version.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `M-x gud-gdb` to use the old gud mode (i.e. without the `mi` interaction).  Less fancy but more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Did you mean 'without' the `mi` interaction?  Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but the `gud-gdb` mode appears to be quite a jump back from '--annotate=3' support.  Particularly the link between debug location and the source.  Is there a way to address this?  When it stops at a break point I get `^Z^Z/home/richard/.../main.cpp:235:5568:beg:0x80a17d3`.

Comment: You shouldn't see things like `^Z^Z/home/richard/.../main.cpp:235:5568:beg:0x80a17d3`, so I suspect GDB is not in the right annotation mode.  For `gud-gdb`, GDB should be started as `gdb --fullname ...` IIUC.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `gdb-ui` from emacs 23 will still work in emacs 24:

- Find a copy of `gdb-ui` (In my case `gdb-ui.el.gz` and `gdb-ui.elc` from a backup)
- Place these into a directory (I have added `~/emacs-modes`)

Then add the following to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs-modes")
(require 'gdb-ui)
```

Running `gdb` will now use the old `--annotate=3` mode rather than `-i=mi`.